# how to drag and drop custom objects into window , using pyqt

Tags: python, python-2.7, drag-and-drop, pyqt, pyqt4

What i like to achieve is to make a drag and drop UI for my application . Something like what Qt Designer provides. Where you can drag an element and place it in the window.

I have a done some PyQt programming before, but not of this complexity.

can anyone direct me, on how to accomplish this.

Example :

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395799/pyqt4-drag-and-drop

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdrag.html#exec